# Site is not-secured in cypress window

Tags: https, cypress, sockjs

Our site is secured & chrome also show "Secured" lock icon. But when I ran cypress automation test, cypress window shows "Not secured". So I got below error on console and page is not loaded.

*SecurityError: An insecure SockJS connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS*

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0i0r.png)

How to fix this issue

Note:We have sockJs client. So sockjs-client throws this error.

sockjs-client/lib/main.js:79

```
if (loc.protocol === 'https:' && !secure) { 
   throw new Error('SecurityError: An insecure SockJS connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS'); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just hack around this error (as opposed to e.g. not throwing the error on localhost in the first place), you can mute it like this.

I've taken into account what you wrote in comments, and while I don't know the cause, let's bring out the big guns. If this doesn't work, then I don't know.

This assumes you're using `cy.visit` to load your page. Also, this won't work for non-page tests (e.g. when you don't load a page at all).

```js
// cypress/support/index.js

Cypress.Commands.overwrite( 'visit', (origFn, url, opts = {}) => {
  // normalize arguments
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if ( typeof url == 'string' ) {
    opts.url = url;
  } else {
    opts = url;
  }

  // overwrite onBeforeLoad
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  const _onBeforeLoad = opts.onBeforeLoad;
  opts.onBeforeLoad = function ( win ) {

    // monkey-patch `window.onerror` callback which Cypress uses for error
    //  handling. When cypress starts to use `addEventListener`, then we're
    //  in trouble.
    // Note: By this time, Cypress should have added the callback. If this
    //  wasn't the case, we'd have to add a setter on `window.onerror` and
    //  ensure we wrap the callback, there.
    const _onerror = win.onerror;
    win.onerror = function ( err ) {
      if (
        typeof err === 'string' &&
        err.includes('SecurityError: An insecure SockJS')
      ) return;

      _onerror.call(win, ...arguments);
    }
    // add a regular listener in order to prevent logging to devTools console
    win.addEventListener('error', ev => {
      if (
        ev && typeof ev.message === 'string' &&
        ev.message.includes('SecurityError: An insecure SockJS')
      ) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
    });

    // call user-supplied `onBeforeLoad` callback, if supplied
    if ( _onBeforeLoad ) _onBeforeLoad(win);
  }
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  return origFn(opts);
});
```

Also see [turning off all uncaught exception handling](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Uncaught-Exceptions)

Comment: Thanks @dewlle. I have added those lines in index.js, but issue still persist. I have added error image in my query

Comment: Looks like the error is thrown outside of tests. Can you post your failing spec file (you can strip unrelated code)?

Comment: WTBS, I've updated my answer, see if it works, now.